# android animation problem

Tags: android

i wanna play scale(from 0 -> 1) animation on 6 balls , duration is 1000 ms on each ball.

and each animation have to wait the previous for 200ms.

ex :

anim1.start -> delay 200ms -> anim2.start (while anim1 is playing) -> ........

but i always got all 6 balls animations started at the same time  , i don't know why , could

somebody tell me??

```
// show animation.
    public void showBallAnimation(View v) {

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ball_container);

        RelativeLayout rl;

        ScaleAnimation scaleAnim1 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        scaleAnim1.setDuration(500);
        scaleAnim1.setStartOffset(0);
        scaleAnim1.setFillAfter(true);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) ll.getChildAt(0);
        rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rl.startAnimation(scaleAnim1);

        ScaleAnimation scaleAnim2 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        scaleAnim2.setDuration(500);
        scaleAnim2.setStartOffset(200);
        scaleAnim2.setFillAfter(true);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) ll.getChildAt(1);
        rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rl.startAnimation(scaleAnim2);

        ScaleAnimation scaleAnim3 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        scaleAnim3.setDuration(500);
        scaleAnim3.setStartOffset(400);
        scaleAnim3.setFillAfter(true);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) ll.getChildAt(2);
        rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rl.startAnimation(scaleAnim3);

        // Animation anim4 =
        // AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
        // R.anim.ball_scale4);
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnim4 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        scaleAnim4.setDuration(500);
        scaleAnim4.setStartOffset(600);
        scaleAnim4.setFillAfter(true);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) ll.getChildAt(3);
        rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rl.startAnimation(scaleAnim4);

    }
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - have you set a start time? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartTime(long) - link not quite working, search for "setStartTime". Also "As an alternative to startAnimation(), you can define a starting time for the animation with Animation.setStartTime(), then assign the animation to the View with View.setAnimation()." - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Answer (score 6):

You should change `r1.startAnimation(scaleAnimX)` to `r1.setAnimation(scaleAnimX)`

Calling `startAnimation()` will start the Animation instantly, ignoring any time offset or start time.

Calling `setAnimation()` will take into account any time specifications.